# How to make menu click disappear on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, click

I'm a bit new, so I have a menu that triggers on hover and click. (if you hover the options will show and out will disappear while click will make it stay until you click on something else) but I want to know if its possible to make the click event disappear if I were to hover on another menu because right now if I click on it and hover on something else I'm going to have two menu option list when I want only the hover one to work. I'm sorry if this question was already answered but I can't seem to find it

Thank you very much

Comment: hey, welcome to stack overflow. please give us a [mcve] of what you have tried so far.

Comment: OK sorry next time I'll be more detailed, but no need to help me on this situation anymore. While reviewing the code I found out that their was an event in the code that caused the error in the Jquery which made it malfunction.

Comment: Great. BTW, that's one of the reasons putting together a demo that replicates the problem is a good idea. Often during the process of replicating the functionality for us, you'll stumble upon the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both a hover & click event, you may need to set up multiple event listeners:

Simple concept example:

```
el.on('mouseenter', function(e){ //for hover
  disableClicks();
}

el.on('mouseleave', function(e){ //for hover
  enableClicks();
}
```

Also, why not just simplify and only have action that is enabled on hover or click?  Since the menu will be open already by the time they click...